# Report Builder Column Chart

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart, reportbuilder3.0

Could please help me how to go about a Column(Vertical) Chart doing the following:

x-axis = Count of orders.
y-axis = Months
series = OrderType.

So basically I see the following info on the chart:

Jan 2000 I see OrderType (i) has 3 Orders, (m) has 9 orders, (l) has 6.
So this I can probably figure out, the difficult part I want to know which I have no Idea how to do is:
I want a dropdown to change the y-axis view.
The dropdown would contain : Week, Month, Year, Day.
When selecting "Week" for example, the y-axis should render,calculate and display the y-axis according to week

Much like a calendar works. I am not even sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. I would suggest that you have two overviews instead, one for the yearly view and one for the monthly-year break down. 
FYI, I think X- axis should be the Month/Year. And Y axis should be the amounts and series can be the order types.

Comment: You are right, does not seem possible this way, if you do want to be able to have more flexibility is to make a site and use the ReportViewer control. I thank you for acknowledge what I already feared for.